# Using ant design vue in html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ant-design-vue

How to use ant design vue in html.

I tried to get this library with npm and got access to these files antd.js, antd-with-locales.js.map, antd.js.map, antd-with-locales.min.js, antd. min.js, antd-with-locales.min.js.LICENSE.txt, antd.min.js.LICENSE.txt, antd-with-locales.min.js.map, antd.min.js.map, reset. css, antd-with-locales.js. I tried to enter them into the code with the script tag, but I get an error in the console.
This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ant-design-vue@4.0.3/dist/reset.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/dayjs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/weekday.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/localeData.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/weekOfYear.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/weekYear.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/advancedFormat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/quarterOfYear.js"></script>
    <title>My first ant design vue page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <template>
        <a-button>Add</a-button>
    </template>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ant-design-vue@4.0.3/dist/antd.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        import { Button } from 'ant-design-vue';
        const ButtonGroup = Button.Group;

        export default {
            components: {
                AButton: Button,
                AButtonGroup: ButtonGroup,
            },
        };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is my error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at first.html:24:9)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What's your code and the error?

Comment: @gre_gor Unfortunately, the document does not provide examples for noobs like me

Comment: If you give me a simple example, my problem will be solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use it as Single File Component (*.vue), which requires a build step, which makes files usable for the browser.

If you want to use the library directly in the browser, you need to use the global `antd` variable.

```js
const { Button } = antd;
const ButtonGroup = Button.Group;

Vue.createApp({
  components: {
    AButton: Button,
    AButtonGroup: ButtonGroup,
  },
}).mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/weekday.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/localeData.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/weekOfYear.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/weekYear.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/advancedFormat.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/quarterOfYear.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ant-design-vue@4.0.3/dist/antd.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ant-design-vue@4.0.3/dist/reset.css">
<div id="app">
  <a-button>Add</a-button>
</div>
```

Instead of manually including components, you can just extract all of them from the `antd` variable. And you probably want to register them globally, so they are available in your custom components, without explicitly including them individually.

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data: () => ({
    "text": "",
  }),
});
Object.values(antd).forEach(o => {
  if (typeof o == "object" && o.name) {
    app.component(o.name, o);
  }
});
app.mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/weekday.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/localeData.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/weekOfYear.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/weekYear.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/advancedFormat.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs/plugin/quarterOfYear.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ant-design-vue@4.0.3/dist/antd.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ant-design-vue@4.0.3/dist/reset.css">
<div id="app">
  <a-button-group>
    <a-button @click="text = 'A'">A</a-button>
    <a-button @click="text = 'B'">B</a-button>
    <a-button @click="text = 'C'">C</a-button>
  </a-button-group>
  <a-alert v-if="text" show-icon :message="text"></a-alert>
</div>
```

For serious work with Vue (and Ant Design), you should look into [how to use *.vue files with vite](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/tooling.html#project-scaffolding).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help in solving my problem